# Pingfederate Outbound Provisioning

Tags: provisioning, outbound, pingfederate, scim

I am trying to configure outbound provisioning in PingFederate 7.2.0. When I try to get a user from Active Directory using provmgr.bat it fails to do so. Shows the following output in my screen-

```
D:\pingfederate-7.2.0\pingfederate\bin>provmgr.bat  -c 2 --show-user -g 1cbc1a1f4a3a4431b8ada8454ee77857

User not found in internal database.

User not found in LDAP!
```

The provmgr.log says

```
DEBUG main org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource - Not using LDAP pooling
DEBUG main org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource - Trying provider Urls: ldaps://10.242.169.171
DEBUG main org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource - AuthenticationSource not set - using default implementation
DEBUG main org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource - Not using LDAP pooling
DEBUG main org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource - Trying provider Urls: ldaps://10.242.169.171
DEBUG main com.pingidentity.configservice.impl.ConfigStoreImpl - Loading config file: D:\pingfederate-7.2.0\pingfederate\server\default\data\config-store\com.pingidentity.provisioner.directory.spring.PagingLdapTemplate.xml
DEBUG main com.pingidentity.provisioner.directory.spring.PagingLdapTemplate - Page size: 500
DEBUG main com.pingidentity.provisioner.directory.spring.PagingLdapTemplate - VLV sort key:cn
DEBUG main com.pingidentity.provisioner.directory.spring.PagingLdapTemplate - Paging algorithm: auto
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
INFO main com.pingidentity.provisioner.mapping.IdentityMapper - Empty field, ignoring.
DEBUG main org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.DirContextPoolableObjectFactory - Creating a new READ_ONLY DirContext
DEBUG main org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource - Got Ldap context on server 'ldaps://10.242.169.171'
DEBUG main org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.DirContextPoolableObjectFactory - Created new READ_ONLY DirContext='javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext@147890f'
DEBUG main org.springframework.ldap.pool.validation.DefaultDirContextValidator - DirContext 'javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext@147890f' passed validation.
```

As it says it is able to create a DirContext I think the connection to Active Directory is working. I have triple checked the base DN and other parameters. And those are fine. Can anybody tell me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space before your -c  argument.

Here is the [PingFedederate v6.6](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF66/SaaS+Provisioning+CLI) documentation on SaaS Provisioning.